# How can we increment a string variable within a for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in $(ls);
do
    j=1
    echo "$i"
```

not expected Output:-

```
autodeploy
bin
config
console-ext
edit.lok
```

need Output like below if give input 2 it should print "bin" based on below condition, but I want out put like Directory list

```
1.)autodeploy
2.)bin
3.)config
4.)console-ext
5.)edit.lok
```

and if i like as input:- 2 then it should print `"bin"`

Comment: Never use `for i in $(ls)....` see [**BashPitfalls - Greg's Wiki**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls).

Comment: Thanks Much David :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), a `while read` loop is the correct way to read content line-by-line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

enumerate() {
  local line i
  i=0
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    ((++i))
    printf '%d.) %s\n' "$i" "$line"
  done
}

ls | enumerate
```

However, `ls` is *not* an appropriate tool for programmatic use; the above is acceptable if the results of `ls` are only for human consumption, but not if they're going to be parsed by a machine -- see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

---

If you want to list files and let the user choose among them by number, pass the results of a glob expression to `select`:

```
select filename in *; do
  echo "$filename" && break
done
```

Comment: Fisrt of all Thank you very much :)   I am new in scripting so can you please guide me for user choose among them by number, pass the results of a glob expression to select: for this #!/usr/bin/env bash

enumerate() {
  local line i
  i=0
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    ((++i))
    printf '%d.) %s\n' "$i" "$line"
  done
}

ls | enumerate

Comment: Eh? The latter approach, the `select filename in *`, does the "pass the results of a glob expression to select" thing. No need for the `enumerate` function at all in that case.

Comment: `ls | enumerate` pipes the output of `ls` as input (the argument list) to the function `enumerate` defined above that line.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, perhaps you mean "as opposed to the argument list" for the parenthetical?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean in your question by *like Directory list*, but following your example, you do not need to write a loop:

```
ls|nl -s '.)' -w 1
```

If you want to avoid *ls*, you can do the following (but be careful - this only works if the directory entries do not contain white spaces (because this would make *fmt* to break them into two lines):

```
echo *|fmt -w 1 |nl -s '.)' -w 1
```